# knitr: output hook with an output.lines= option that works like echo=2:6

Tags: r, hook, knitr

In a book project, I have lots of output I'd like to abbreviate, by selecting only a subset of the lines, and adding `...` to indicate that some output has been elided.  For example, in the output from `summary(lm())`, I might want to print just the table of coefficients, and have it appear as follows:

```
 >summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris))
...
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         5.0060     0.0728  68.762  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030   9.033 8.77e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030  15.366  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
...
```

I wrote the following output hook that works with a chunk option, `output.lines=` and accepts a single number, n, meaning print only lines `1:n`, sort of like `head()` would do:

```
  # get the default output hook
  hook_output <- knit_hooks$get("output")

  knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
    lines <- options$output.lines
    if (is.null(lines)) {
      hook_output(x, options)  # pass to default hook
    }
    else {
      x <- unlist(stringr::str_split(x, "\n"))
      if (length(x) > lines) {
        # truncate the output, but add ....
        x <- c(head(x, lines), "...\n")
      }
      # paste these lines together
      x <- paste(x, collapse = "\n")
      hook_output(x, options)
    }
  })
```

I've tried to generalize this to accept a (consecutive) vector of line numbers as shown below, but it doesn't seem to
work and I can't tell why.  It is also not as general as I'd like, because passing `output.lines=1:12` should print only lines 1:12 ..., and like the option `echo=`, it would be nice to use `output.lines = -1:3` to get `...` followed by all remaining lines.

```
  # knitr hook function to allow an output.lines option
  # e.g., 
  #   output.lines=12 prints lines 1:12 ...
  #   output.lines=3:15 prints lines ... 3:15 ...

   knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
     lines <- options$output.lines
     if (is.null(lines)) {
       hook_output(x, options)  # pass to default hook
     }
     else {
       x <- unlist(stringr::str_split(x, "\n"))
       more <- "...\n"
       if (length(lines)==1) {        # first n lines
         if (length(x) > lines) {
           # truncate the output, but add ....
           x <- c(head(x, lines), more)
         }
       }
       else {
         x <- c(more, x[lines], more)
      }
       # paste these lines together
       x <- paste(x, collapse = "\n")
       hook_output(x, options)
     }
   })
```

I think this is a more general problem than just mine, so maybe this would be a welcome addition to knitr.

-Michael

Comment: Instead of a bare `-1:3` give `output.lines=-c(1:3)` a try. Also, in using the `output` hook you get control over _each_ output _within_ the chunk, not the full chunk output, to emulate the `echo` behavior I think you'd need to use the full chunk and distinguish between `source` (backticks followed by r) and `output` (just the backticks), and my guess is that you'd want to match them as pairs since the ending `source` would be just the backticks...

Answer (score 13):

I do not see why it should not work, either. Thell pointed out a mistake in the comment above (`-1:3` should be `-(1:3)`), which might be the reason. Other than that, it works well for me:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
hook_output <- knit_hooks$get("output")
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
   lines <- options$output.lines
   if (is.null(lines)) {
     return(hook_output(x, options))  # pass to default hook
   }
   x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
   more <- "..."
   if (length(lines)==1) {        # first n lines
     if (length(x) > lines) {
       # truncate the output, but add ....
       x <- c(head(x, lines), more)
     }
   } else {
     x <- c(more, x[lines], more)
   }
   # paste these lines together
   x <- paste(c(x, ""), collapse = "\n")
   hook_output(x, options)
 })
```

Normal output.

```{r test}
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris))
```

The first 4 lines.

```{r test, output.lines=4}
```

Remove the first 8 lines.

```{r test, output.lines=-(1:8)}
```

From 8 to 15.

```{r test, output.lines=8:15}
```
````

[image: results after modifying the the output hook]

Comment: Could `R` module(s) with hooks be defined anywhere in a project (directory-wise) and then sourced in a project-wide `knitr`-focused *global* configuration file?

Answer (score 9):

Thell's comment and Yihui's test case allowed me to generalize this slightly so it now does just what I want.

In particular, `output.lines=1:12` works the same as `output.lines=12` and omits the initial `...`.  Similarly for
the case of `output.lines=-(1:8)` which prints the initial `...` but omits it if the last line is included in the
range.

This now meets my needs, and might be sufficiently useful to others to include as a new knitr chunk option. 
From a design point of view, the only thing that might be changed is to only supply the **range** of desired lines, e.g.,
`output.lines=c(1,8)` or `output.lines=-c(1,8)`, since it would be very messy and possibly confusing to allow for the `...`s in non-consecutive line selections.

E.g., with the current function, `output.lines=sample(1:15,10)` will work, and actually do something useful for a chunk
that prints a data frame, similarly to `some(iris)` from the `car` package.  But, when I want that, I use `some()` directly.
This output hook is only designed to select a range of lines from printed output from a function that is too long to
usefully include in a printed document, or when you want to focus attention on just a part of the output and indicate
that some lines have been omitted.

```
  # knitr hook function to allow an output.lines option
  # e.g., 
  #   output.lines=12 prints lines 1:12 ...
  #   output.lines=1:12 does the same
  #   output.lines=3:15 prints lines ... 3:15 ...
  #   output.lines=-(1:8) removes lines 1:8 and prints ... 9:n ...
  #   No allowance for anything but a consecutive range of lines

library(knitr)
hook_output <- knit_hooks$get("output")
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
   lines <- options$output.lines
   if (is.null(lines)) {
     return(hook_output(x, options))  # pass to default hook
   }
   x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
   more <- "..."
   if (length(lines)==1) {        # first n lines
     if (length(x) > lines) {
       # truncate the output, but add ....
       x <- c(head(x, lines), more)
     }
   } else {
     x <- c(if (abs(lines[1])>1) more else NULL, 
            x[lines], 
            if (length(x)>lines[abs(length(lines))]) more else NULL
           )
   }
   # paste these lines together
   x <- paste(c(x, ""), collapse = "\n")
   hook_output(x, options)
 })
```

Comment: +1 for both Q and A. Excellent function! I thought about implementing a similar one for my code, but ran across your post. Thank you for sharing, I will gladly borrow it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to make this as a default option in RMarkdown? Or can I store this in some kind of source file that I call in every RMarkdown document I create? It's just a very useful option and I'd like to not have to define it in every document.